# Macro: Removing group of rows associated with cell in first column based on criteria, then deleting blank rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a difficult time merging code to accomplish my goal. I am working between two sheets within one workbook. Column "A" references an item that may have multiple rows in column "C". "C" could have thousands of label codes, but there are 52 label codes that are listed in sheet "SheetCode".  What my goal is to look at an item and see if it has one of the 52 label codes and if so then remove the item and all rows below it until the next Item in Column "A" label number. I want my macro to:

1. Search Column C for any value listed in sheet "SheetCode" (A2:A53)
2. If found, reference the associated populated cell in Column A and delete all rows below until it runs into the next populated cell in Column A, but continues to search the rest of column "C" for more (A2:A53) values.
3. Loop

I posted 2 images. The SheetCode worksheet has the list of values. I adde conditional formatting so that any cell value in main spreadsheet is colored. Ultimately the code should then delete all rows below the Column A value. This example would show rows 14-21 and 29-44 deleted.

Here is what I have so far. My problem is I want to avoid

```
Sub Remove_TBI_AB()
Const TEST_COLUMN As String = "C"
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim EndRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ActiveSheet

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, TEST_COLUMN).End(xlUp).Row
    EndRow = Lastrow
    For i = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i, TEST_COLUMN).Value2 Like "161000" Then
            'Here I could at continuous "_or" and then in next line add the next code to find, but I have the list and would rather reference the list of values

            .Rows(i & ":" & EndRow).Delete

            EndRow = i - 1
        ' Here I need code to delete all cells below the associated value in Column A until the next populated cell. 

            EndRow = i - 1
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

SheetCode; values to target
[image: SheetCode; values to target]

Main Worksheet
[image: Main Worksheet]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track, with some use of arrays and worksheet functions it could be completed; the key is that we will iterate backward "by item zone" instead of by individual rows. For each item zone, if at least one code is matched in the `SheetCode` list, the whole zone is deleted.

```
Sub Remove_TBI_AB()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    On Error GoTo Cleanup

    Dim codes As Range: Set codes = Worksheets("Sheetcode").Range("A2:A53")
    Dim lastrow As Long, startRow As Long
    '[startRow, lastRow] mark the start/end of current item
    With Worksheets("Main")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row
        Do While lastrow > 1
            startRow = lastrow
            Do Until Len(Trim(.Cells(startRow, 1).Value2)) > 0
                startRow = startRow - 1
            Loop ' find the beginning of current item

            With .Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & lastrow) ' range of current item codes
                If Application.SumProduct(Application.CountIf(codes, .Value2)) > 0 Then
                    .EntireRow.Delete ' at least one code was matched
                End If
            End With
            lastrow = startRow - 1
        Loop ' restart with next item above
    End With

Cleanup:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: This works almost perfectly. If you look at Column C in the main sheet, you'll see that some values code values have an appended extra digit or two on the end. I found a workaround where is add a function to keep the first 6 numbers and delete the rest (all codes are 6 numbers).

Comment: the function is easy, just =LEFT(C2, 6) then I dragged it down. But then I have to copy whole column and paste value. Is there an easier way to add this into the macro?

Comment: @AlexBadilla I dont have the testing data anymore now (it was 3 days ago). Would you try this modification: instead of `Application.SumProduct(Application.CountIf(codes, .Value2))`, try `Application.SumProduct(Application.CountIf(codes, Evaluate("transpose(Left(" & .Address & ", 6))")))`

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Conversely to the intention of this macro, if I wanted to delete all BUT the items that have these codes, would I just change the > 0 to < 0? It seems like this is the only part that affects this:

With .Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & lastrow) ' range of current item codes  If Application.SumProduct(Application.CountIf(codes, .Value2)) > 0 Then
                  .EntireRow.Delete ' at least one code was matched

Comment: @AlexBadilla `>0` should be replaced by  `= 0` for that.